# Does Mortal Kombat Komplete Edition on Steam have Freddy Krueger?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9, mortal-kombat-komplete-edition

Does **[Mortal Kombat Komplete Edition on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/237110/?snr=1_7_15__13)** give the opportunity to play for **Freddy Krueger**?

Comment: why did I downvote: the answer to your question is clear on the steam store, so you didn't even try to read before posting your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it says on the store page for this game:

> The newest chapter of the iconic fighting franchise is now available!
>   Experience the deadliest tournament with all the kombatants and their
>   unique fatalities. Players enter the realm to face the Kombatants in
>   Mortal Kombat Komplete Edition, delivering all of the downloadable
>   content (DLC), including intrepid warriors Skarlet, Kenshi and Rain,
>   as well as the notorious dream stalker **Freddy Krueger**. Additionally,
>   the game offers 15 Klassic Mortal Kombat Skins and three Klassic
>   Fatalities (Scorpion, Sub-Zero and Reptile).

Mortal Komplete Edition contains all DLC released back in 2011 when it was originally released.

So yes, you can play him.